# range() column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame which looks like:

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'col2': [2, 1, 3]
})
```

The goal is to apply range on `col2` and get new DataFrame which will represent this data:

```
a 1
a 2
b 1
c 1
c 2
c 3
```

So far I got to the point having 2 DataFrames:

```
requests_series = pd.Series([np.arange(0, col2, 1) + 1 for col1, col2 in zip(data_df.col1, data_df.col2)], data_df.index, name='requests')
requests_df = requests_series.to_frame()
data_df.pop('col2')
```

and now stuck how to merge them desired way.

I rather looking for an efficient way, because on production it will end up dealing with 10M rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `repeat` and then `groupby().cumcount()`:

```
(data_df.loc[data_df.index.repeat(data_df['col2'])]
        .assign(col2=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1)
    )
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0    a     1
0    a     2
1    b     1
2    c     1
2    c     2
2    c     3
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!